# How to associate more tests to a testcase in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

Currently we are able to associate only one mstest to a testcase in azure devops. I want to associate more than one test to a testcase. Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

> How to associate more tests to a testcase in azure devops

For this issue, I think it is not available to associate more than one test to a test case.  A test can only be associated with one test case. For example: suppose we associate multiple tests into a test case. When running this test case, some of the tests successes and some of the tests failures, we can't determine whether the test case is successful or not, so this is unreasonable.

If you want to run multiple tests,you need to create multiple test cases.You can also try to create a test Plan or test suite, then add multiple test cases to the test suite or test plan, then run the test suite or test plan.
Please refer to [Create test plans and test suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

Comment: Suppose an acceptance criteria has one testcase and this testcase has a unit test and an UI automation test using selenium, how do we link it to the same testcase.

Comment: adding the same test case again just for associating the test, is a tedious task and not good for reporting purposes i guess.

Comment: I think it is not feasible to link  these two tests into a test case.The recommended way is to create a test suite and add two test cases,each test case links to a test.

Comment: How about creating a test which calls all other tests for the testcase. And we associate this master test to the testcase.

Comment: You can include multiple test methods in a test and then associate this test with testcase.